# Wordpress + Postgresql

Tags: database

I’ve painted myself into a corner.

I hired someone to build a database with all kinds of cool search features and such.  The programmer wasn't aware that my site is built on Wordpress.  He wrote his stuff using postgresql and go.  And we’ve already made a lot of progress (everything is hosted in his sandbox account).

Turns out that Wordpress doesn’t support postgresql.

There is a plugin that “claims” to resolve the issue - https://wordpress.org/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/.  But I don’t like using plugins in general.  They slow down the site.

It’s also possible to use iframes.  But this might be slower – and I don’t have as much control.

Has anyone faced a similar situation?

Is it possible to import his database/search into my wordpress?  Or will I have to build everything from scratch in a database language that is already compatible with wordpress?

Anyway – I’m pretty experienced with wordpress, but I don’t have any database or programming knowledge (none – zilch).

Apologies for the “noobness” of this question.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to [read his first](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3933/31545)

Comment: No offense to you or your developer, but I think it is time to hire a developer with some experience in WordPress.  It's almost certainly possible to port the postgres db to mysql, although depending on the amount and complexity of queries, views, etc written, it could get pretty complicated.  These mistakes happen, and should be a learning experience for both of you.  I don't think we can give you a proper answer here because it would be both too broad (porting a postgres db to mysql), and too localized to your problem.  Best of luck.